# Creating a background window (i.e. do NOT grab the focus)

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

How can I create a window in perl/Tk so that it does not grab focus? Ideally it should be "blinking" on the task bar, grabbing attention, yet not irritating the user.

*This is probably a duplicate, but I'm having trouble googling it...*

Comment: If it is irritating, it is a bug.

Comment: @Svante: Mostly so, but there are exceptions such as alarm clocks and traffic lights.

Comment: I think our disagreement is just linguistic.  Traffic lights should not be irritating either.  They should give a clear and obvious indication.  If they are irritating, their targets will try to find ways not to see them.

Comment: @Svante I think your initial comment was right after all. I'll restate the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See perldoc Tk::Wm

```
$ perl -MTk -le " my $mw = tkinit; $mw->iconify; $mw->lower; MainLoop; "

$ perl -MTk -le ' my $mw = tkinit; $mw->iconify; $mw->lower; MainLoop; '
```